# Parameter to reentrant Bison parser not reflected properly as argument to yyerror

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I am working on a reentrant Bison parser. To focus on the problem, I have, I have carved out the minimal code from my parser and modified it to make it a working example. Here it is:

```
    %code top {
      typedef void* yyscan_t;
      typedef struct {
          char tmpString1[1000];
      } parseSupportStructType;
    }

    %define api.pure full
    %locations
    %param { yyscan_t scanner }
    %parse-param { parseSupportStructType* parseSupportStruct}

    %code {
      int yylex(YYSTYPE* yylvalp, YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t scanner);
      void yyerror(YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t unused, parseSupportStructType* parseSupportStruct,  const char* msg);
      char *yyget_text (yyscan_t);
    }

    %union {
       char *strval; 
    }

    %define parse.error verbose

    %token TERMINAL1 TERMINAL2
    %type <strval> TERMINAL1 TERMINAL2

    %%  
    START :  TERMINAL1 TERMINAL2
             {   
             }   
    %%  
    void yyerror(YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t unused, parseSupportStructType* parseSupportStruct,  const char* msg);

      strcpy(parseSupportStruct->tmpString1, "someString");
    }
```

The lex file is minimal with just rules for returning tokens TERMINAL1 and TERMINAL2. 
When I try to build my executable, I get the following error:

```
 test.y:35:36: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘->’ token
            strcpy(parseSupportStruct->tmpString1, "someString");
                                     ^~  
 test.y:36:9: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
          }   
          ^   
 recipe for target 'test.tab.o' failed
 make: *** [test.tab.o] Error 1
```

I suspect I am doing some basic C mistake or yyerror does not get the parser param argument correctly as declared in %parse-param. On examining the .tab.c file, I noticed that the invocation of yyerror is:

```
         yyerror (&yylloc, scanner, parseSupportStruct, YY_("syntax error"));
```

Compare this with the declaration (passed thru) in the same file:

```
      void yyerror(YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t unused, parseSupportStructType* parseSupportStruct,  const char* msg);
```

The type of parseSupportStruct argument in the invocation is incorrect.

PLEASE HELP.  I am programming in C after a long break so may be just some basic C issues?

Comment: Indeed. Look at line 33 where you declare `yyerror` rather than opening a definition.

Comment: @rici Thanks. How did I miss that? -:)

Comment: @rici I must say that you are a total guru in Bison/Lex  and surely in other areas too.